# Why use connect() when we can use Provider, useDispatch(), useSelector() to access store, dispatch and other important things React-Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

By using `Provider`, `useSelector()`, `useDispatch()`, etc we can access all the important things, then why do we get need to use `connect()` ?

Answer (score 2):

`connect` is an older API from before React introduced hooks. If you are using only functional components with hooks, you don't need to use `connect`, but if you need to use Redux from a class-based component, you will.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use both `connect` and `useSelector`. use one of them only. connect is an old way. `useSelector` is new and more easy.